# Re-partition my system which has dual operating system (Win7 and Win 8) and install a fresh Win8 OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, formatting, bootrepair

I have got a boot problem when i am trying to open Windows 8. When I switch on my laptop, it asks which OS to boot in (i.e. either Win7 or Win8). But now, when I switch on the laptop, the system is entering to **Automatic Repair mode** and after some time I get an error in booting saying that **"There is a problem in the File StartTrail.txt"** and it gives options for using my other OS (Win 7) and also asking for TroubleShoot, Restore, Reset.

When I opt for Win 7, it is booting.

I don't understand what's the problem, and I want to remove all these stuff, re-partition the whole Hard Drive and install a fresh Windows 8 OS.

**I am using a Dual Boot** with Window 7 and Windows 8

Summary:

- I have not installed Win7 and Win8 in the same Drive. I have installed it on two different drive.
- Previously, both the operating systems used to boot well.
- Laptop is automatically entering to Repair Mode and giving an error booting.
- Then it is giving two options: 1. To ShutDown 2: Advanced Options
- In advanced Options it gave me an Option to Boot another OS. When I click that, it gave option to select Win8 and Win7

How do I install the Fresh OS??

Comment: i have not installed Win7 and Win8 in the same Drive. I have installed it two different drive. previously, both the operating systems used to boot well. But today i am unable to boot Win8. Lap is automatically entering to Repair Mode and giving an error booting. I did'nt understand what's the problem. Then it is Giving two options :1. To ShutDown 2: Advanced Options in That advanced Options it gave me an Option to Boot another OS When i Clicked that, it gave option to Select Win8 and Win7

Comment: i Have Selected Win7 and its working well. but the thing is, as i have Dual OS, it used to give me an option to select which OS to Boot. But now, it is directly entering to some Automatic repair Mode and Giving me all that above process which i did'nt get before

Comment: So, you want to remove both the operating systems and reinstall a fresh windows 8? ie you will only have one fresh windows 8 on your computer no more dual boots?

Comment: When you are asked for advanced options, is it with a black DOS style screen or bright blue Windows 8 style screen> Have you tried **refreshing** your Windows 8 from advanced options > troubleshoot > **refresh your pc**. If that doesn't work and you want to reset win8, then click **reset your pc** from the same screen.

Comment: @shub I think you don't get his point. He said that he clicked in the advanced options then there is no way he could do that in the DOS style screen but only in windows 8/8.1 boot menu. Also if he can't get his system repair without a disc, he could do that with a disc which could get it done. Also to refresh, he would need a windows 8 disc. Repairing from a windows 8 disc will get the problem  solved in no matter of time.

Comment: @Hunter Sorry, I overlooked the word `click`. I didn't know that you needed a disk for refresh, but now I know, thanks

Comment: @shub Yes, am getting a Bright Blue Windows 8 Style Screen. Initially when i switch on my laptop, it enters to **Automatic repair**. Then gives me some error and two options : **1:Shutdown 2:Advanced Options**
in Advanced Options am getting 4 more options: **1:Continue 2: Choose another OS 3:Troubleshoot 4:Turn Off PC**
In Troubleshoot i have another 3 options **1:Refresh 2:Reset 3:Advanced Options**
When i choose another OS: **Am able to get an option to select Windows 7 and also Windows 8**

Comment: Is there any way that i can remove the Dual boot and install single OS (Windows 8) and also make new partitions??

Comment: Thank you @shub for immediate reply, But my problem is still consisting, please help me out.

Comment: Sorry, AFAIK there is no way to do anything without a install dvd...